# Pandas mean with neighbor zeros?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data:

```
1: 0
2: 800
3: 800
4: 800
5: 800
6: 0
7: 0
8: 800
9: 800
10: 0
11: 800
12: 0
```

Now I would like to replace all the 800s which is a neighbor to any zeros (before or after) with 400 (which is really the mean of 800 and the neighboring 0).

End result:

```
1: 0
2: 400
3: 800
4: 800
5: 400
6: 0
7: 0
8: 400
9: 400
10: 0
11: 400
12: 0
```

What is the proper way to do this using a Pandas DataFrame?

Answer (score 1):

You can halve your series based on the union of 2 Boolean conditions:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [0, 800, 800, 800, 800, 0, 0, 800, 800, 0, 800, 0]})

df.loc[df['col'].shift().eq(0) | df['col'].shift(-1).eq(0), 'col'] //= 2

print(df)

    col
0     0
1   400
2   800
3   800
4   400
5     0
6     0
7   400
8   400
9     0
10  400
11    0
```

Comment: Doesn't you need to apply that only where the values are equal to 800?

Comment: @DanielMesejo, *Possibly*, but the question seems to imply this is some kind of "averaging" logic, i.e. all values next to `0` need to be halved. I'll happily amend if OP clarifies further.

Comment: Touching only the non-zero values would be ideal. The above had a side effect of   changing the zeros to display like "-0.00" instead of "0.00". Why?

Comment: @OlavT, I don't actually see that.. in my example they are just `0`, all integers too. `//` indicates floor division which *should* only give integers. But if you *want* you can add a condition `df['col'].ne(0)`, i.e. `df['col'].shift().eq(0) | df['col'].shift(-1).eq(0) & df['col'].ne(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the example you gave:

```
d = pd.Series([0, 800, 800, 800, 800, 0, 0, 800, 800, 0, 800, 0])

0       0
1     800
2     800
3     800
4     800
5       0
6       0
7     800
8     800
9       0
10    800
11      0
dtype: int64
```

Create filters for each criteria:

```
# Check if value of prev row is 0
up = d.shift(1) == 0
# Check if value of next row is zero
dn = d.shift(-1) == 0
# Check if value of current row is 800
o = d == 800
```

Then find the indices that satisfy the criteria according to your algorithm:

```
idxs = o & (up | dn)
idxs = idxs[idxs == True]
```

Finally change the value at each of the desired indices to 400:

```
d.loc[idxs.index] = 400
```

Which outputs:

```
0       0
1     400
2     800
3     800
4     400
5       0
6       0
7     400
8     400
9       0
10    400
11      0
dtype: int64
```